# Nineagram puzzle aid in Elm

Tags: elm

My first Elm program.

Nineagram is a puzzle that appears in the local newspaper. Given the nine letters for the day, the task is to come up with two five-letter words that share the same middle letter.

Example: `efiimlrtu` has at least one solution of...

```
    f
    e
l i m i t
    u
    r
```

This program is an aid to the solver - you can enter guesses at the first word one at a time. The program will display the remaining letters that would be used for the second word. If a guess could form a solution with one or more of the previous guesses, the guess is displayed in the solutions list along with the other matching word(s).

Example of a players guesses and final program output:

```
Guesses:

    lemur - fiit
    mitre - filu
    unlit - Invalid guess!
    rifle - imtu
    limit - efru
    mufti - eilr
    femur - iilt

Solutions:

    rifle (mufti)
    limit (femur)
    mufti (rifle)
    femur (limit)
```

```hs
module Main exposing (Guess, Model, Msg(..), Nineagram, init, main, update, view)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Attribute, Html, button, div, input, li, text, ul)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick, onInput)



-- MAIN


main =
    Browser.sandbox { init = init, update = update, view = view }



-- MODEL


type alias Model =
    { nineagram : Nineagram
    , guesses : List Guess
    , newguess : Guess
    , newLetters : String
    }


type alias Nineagram =
    { letters : List Char
    }


type alias Guess =
    String


init : Model
init =
    { nineagram = { letters = [] }
    , guesses = []
    , newguess = ""
    , newLetters = ""
    }


remainingLetters : Nineagram -> Guess -> Maybe (List Char)
remainingLetters nineagram guess =
    removeLetters (String.toList guess) nineagram.letters


removeLetters : List Char -> List Char -> Maybe (List Char)
removeLetters lettersToRemove input =
    case lettersToRemove of
        [] ->
            Just input

        letterToRemove :: remainingLettersToRemove ->
            case removeLetter letterToRemove input of
                Nothing ->
                    Nothing

                Just inputWithLetterRemoved ->
                    removeLetters remainingLettersToRemove inputWithLetterRemoved


removeLetter : Char -> List Char -> Maybe (List Char)
removeLetter letter input =
    case input of
        [] ->
            Nothing

        x :: rest ->
            if letter == x then
                Just rest

            else
                case removeLetter letter rest of
                    Nothing ->
                        Nothing

                    Just remainingInput ->
                        Just ([ x ] ++ remainingInput)


type ValidatedGuess
    = ValidGuess Guess (List Char)
    | InvalidGuess Guess


validateGuess : Guess -> Nineagram -> ValidatedGuess
validateGuess guess nineagram =
    if List.length (String.toList guess) /= 5 then
        InvalidGuess guess

    else
        case remainingLetters nineagram guess of
            Nothing ->
                InvalidGuess guess

            Just letters ->
                ValidGuess guess letters


hasSolutions : Nineagram -> List Guess -> Guess -> Bool
hasSolutions nineagram guesses guess =
    guesses |> List.any (\otherguess -> guess |> isSolution nineagram otherguess)


solutions : Nineagram -> List Guess -> Guess -> List Guess
solutions nineagram guesses guess =
    guesses |> List.filter (\otherguess -> guess |> isSolution nineagram otherguess)


isSolution : Nineagram -> Guess -> Guess -> Bool
isSolution nineagram guess otherguess =
    if guess == otherguess || getMiddleLetter guess /= getMiddleLetter otherguess then
        False

    else
        case nineagram.letters |> removeLetters (String.toList guess) of
            Nothing ->
                False

            Just letters ->
                case letters |> removeLetters (removeMiddleLetter (String.toList otherguess)) of
                    Nothing ->
                        False

                    Just [] ->
                        True

                    Just _ ->
                        False


getMiddleLetter : Guess -> List Char
getMiddleLetter guess =
    guess
        |> String.toList
        |> List.take 3
        |> List.drop 2


removeMiddleLetter : List Char -> List Char
removeMiddleLetter guess =
    (guess |> List.take 2) ++ (guess |> List.drop 3)



-- UPDATE


type Msg
    = TypingGuess String
    | SubmitGuess String
    | TypingLetters String
    | SubmitLetters String


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        SubmitGuess newGuess ->
            { model | guesses = model.guesses ++ [ newGuess ] }

        TypingGuess typing ->
            { model | newguess = typing }

        TypingLetters typing ->
            { model | newLetters = typing }

        SubmitLetters newLetters ->
            { model | nineagram = { letters = String.toList newLetters } }



-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    case model.nineagram.letters of
        [] ->
            div []
                [ div []
                    [ input [ placeholder "Nineagram letters", onInput TypingLetters ] []
                    , button [ onClick (SubmitLetters model.newLetters) ] [ text "Submit" ]
                    ]
                ]

        _ ->
            div []
                [ div []
                    [ text (String.fromList model.nineagram.letters)
                    , input [ placeholder "Guess", value model.newguess, onInput TypingGuess ] []
                    , button [ onClick (SubmitGuess model.newguess) ] [ text "Submit" ]
                    ]
                , div []
                    [ text "Guesses:"
                    , ul [] (List.map (\guess -> li [] [ viewGuess model.nineagram guess ]) model.guesses)
                    ]
                , div []
                    [ text "Solutions:"
                    , viewSolutions model.nineagram model.guesses
                    ]
                ]


viewSolutions : Nineagram -> List Guess -> Html Msg
viewSolutions nineagram guesses =
    ul []
        (guesses
            |> List.map
                (\guess ->
                    case validateGuess guess nineagram of
                        ValidGuess _ _ ->
                            if guess |> hasSolutions nineagram guesses then
                                li [] [ text (guess ++ " (" ++ (guess |> solutions nineagram guesses |> String.join ", ") ++ ")") ]

                            else
                                text ""

                        InvalidGuess _ ->
                            text ""
                )
        )


viewGuess : Nineagram -> Guess -> Html msg
viewGuess nineagram guess =
    case validateGuess guess nineagram of
        InvalidGuess invalidGuess ->
            div [] [ text (invalidGuess ++ " - " ++ "Invalid guess!") ]

        ValidGuess validGuess letters ->
            div [] [ text (validGuess ++ " - " ++ String.fromList letters) ]
```

I'm looking for advice on how to make it more idiomatic.

Comment: Not a code review, but more a usability note: it would be more helpful if the middle letter was also shown on the right-hand side (e.g. `lemur - fiimt`).